# Should questions about future works be closed as Primarily Opinion Based?

Tags: discussion, faq, closing-questions, future-works

This is a subject that we've touched upon slightly in the past, but either the questions are based on old close reasons such as "General Reference" and "Too Localized", which are now gone - or they're a little more specific.

- [Movie Trailer Based Questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4762/movie-trailer-based-questions)
- [How do we deal with questions about rumors and release dates?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates)
- [Should questions about the future of a franchise, series, or literary work (groupings) be permitted?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/530/should-questions-asking-about-the-future-of-a-franchise-series-or-literary-wor)
- [Are questions on series which are answered by upcoming episodes "time localised"?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/are-questions-on-series-which-are-answered-by-upcoming-episodes-time-localised)
- [What is the limit for questions about ongoing series?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/521/what-is-the-limit-for-questions-about-ongoing-series)

It feels like lately, we've been getting more of these types of questions, and some of them are closed as  "primarily opinion based" citing that they are speculation based. **Is this the correct way to handle these?**

Let's look at the actual close reason.

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Now, let's look at a recent closed question: [Is anyone in the Hulkbuster armor in the Age of Ultron Trailer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71368/is-anyone-in-the-hulkbuster-armor-in-age-of-ultron-trailer)

> In the trailer, it shows the Hulk battling what appear to be Iron man in his Hulkbuster armor. Is he actually in the armor (his own armor inside of the Hulkbuster) or is Ultron controlling the armor to battle the Hulk?

This question was closed as "primarily opinion based".

It's (probably) not. There are two possible answers. Yes, or No. In all likelihood, The identity of the person/entity inside, or controlling the Hulkbuster Armor will be revealed in the actual movie. *Currently*, all we can do is speculate - and offer our opinions on the matter. We can't provide a reliable answer *right now*, but that doesn't mean we can't *ever* provide a definitive answer.

Over the years, we've had a number of questions that received answers based on the information we had at the time, and which were updated long after with more recent - and *more correct* information.

A great example of this was [Who was the first Avatar?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/who-was-the-first-avatar). Gabe Willard provided an answer based on the information at the time, but was ultimately incorrect. Eventually, *The Legend of Korra* definitively answered this question, and Keen provided a new, more correct answer. (Side note: Pureferret, change your accepted answer!)

We can also look towards [What is that alien in Marvel's Agents of SHIELD?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51303/what-is-that-alien-in-marvels-agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d). At time of posting, we had no definitive answer. We had some clues, so I wrote an answer explaining what we knew, and which might be more or less likely. It took almost 9 months, but we were finally able to provide a definitive answer to this.

The more recent [Who is Peter Quill/Star-Lord's Father?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64654/who-is-peter-quill-star-lords-father) is a similar question. The best answer we have right now is, "We don't know, but the director has said that it's not the same person as in the comics." This question has not been closed.

Now, let's look at another question: [Why are Superman and Batman against each other?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54297/why-are-superman-and-batman-against-each-other) This one has been closed. (Note: Yes, I was one of the close-voters. I've changed my mind since then.)

> I've heard lots about the upcoming Superman vs. Batman movie. But I don't understand why they're fighting against each other. They're both superheroes, trying to fight for the good of humankind, fighting to protect the civilian population. So why are they being pitted against each other? What reasons do they have to fight each other?

Here we have a question about a movie that was 2 years away, when it was asked. I'm not sure the script was even finalized at the time. There was no realistic way for anyone outside of the writing/production team to have a definitive answer. Even now, we can't reliably answer it. But eventually, we will be able to. Sure, it'll languish away, largely forgotten until then. But then the day will come, and we can definitively answer it. Then, the question may become a less-than-great question, since it's basically just asking for a recap of the maguffin, but [we don't require users to have read/watched a work to be allowed to ask a question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/i-havent-read-the-book-watched-the-movie-may-i-ask-a-question-about-it).

Some other questions to consider:

- [X-men: Apocalypse - Taking on an invincible enemy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71628/x-men-apocalypse-taking-on-an-invincible-enemy) Like the Batman/Superman and Hulkbuster questions, we don't have an answer right now, but will eventually.
- [Is there going to be an Iron Man 4 after all prototypes are finally destroyed for good?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71616/is-there-going-to-be-an-iron-man-4-after-all-prtotypes-are-finally-destroyed-fo) Either there will be a new Iron Man movie, or there won't be. Currently, there are no publicized plans. Where does opinion come into the picture?
- [How is Magneto pulling Mystique in the Days of Future Past trailer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56266/how-is-magneto-pulling-mystique-in-the-days-of-future-past-trailer) Prior to release, we had a few decent speculative answers. After it was released, we got a solid definitive answer.
- [What is the plot of Star Wars 7](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48361/what-is-the-plot-of-star-wars-7) Yup, another one I initially VTC'ed. I voted for it before I voted against it. Go ahead and call me a waffler if you like.
- [What character is Benedict Cumberbatch?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22404/what-character-is-benedict-cumberbatch) This one is deleted, so you may not have access to see it, but it asked about the identity of a character in an upcoming movie. It was originally closed as "Too Localized" since we would get a definitive answer once the movie came out. "Too Localized" is no longer a valid close reason.
- [Who is the eye patch woman?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3358/who-is-the-eye-patch-woman) Another question where we didn't have a definitive answer until much later.  This one is especially interesting as Gilles specifically edited the question to make it less time sensitive, extending the life of the value of the question.

**Should we really be closing questions about future works just because we don't have the answer now?**

See also:

- [Should all questions without explicit canon answers be closed?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/should-all-questions-without-explicit-canon-answers-be-closed)
- [Logical speculation in answers](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3484/logical-speculation-in-answers)
- [Questions that provide speculative answers…](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/questions-that-provide-speculative-answers)
- [Can I answer based on my ideas and reasoning of a film without official source?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/can-i-answer-based-on-my-ideas-and-reasoning-of-a-film-without-official-source)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Can we get a custom off-topic close reason for this?

Comment: @amaranth http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/should-we-add-an-off-topic-close-reason-for-future-works?lq=1

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'll go against my philosophical inclination and say "close them".

Why?

1. Closing doesn't mean the question is bad. It just means that it **can not** be answered as-is. (where as is usually applies to question text, but COULD also apply to the question's ecosystem).
2. Closing is NOT PERMANENT. So, we could - and likely will - have a lifecycle of:

   **BAD workflow - today:**

   1. Question asked
   2. **Question generates (likely) several bad opinion based answers. Some are upvoted**
   3. Months/years later, correct canon answer is published
   4. Someone answers with correct answer

   **GOOD workflow:**

   1. Question asked
   2. Question is closed as "not ready yet" (frankly this deserves a special offtopic choice IMHO).

      This prevents any bad answers from being posted
   3. Months/years later, correct canon answer is published
   4. Whoever finds the answer, requests the question to be reopened, via a mod flag, an edit placing the question in re-open queue, or a Meta post.
   5. **Question gets reopened.**
   6. Someone answers with correct answer. Hopefully nobody will be an rude person and post "correct" answer that the requestor-to-open cited before said requestor can answer (happened to me last week and was very annoying).

Comment: You voted to reopen [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55523/who-wrote-the-once-upon-a-time-storybook) which per your post here should be closed.  What's going on?

Comment: @Keen - OK, I just re-read the question. What am I missing? I thought Once Upon a time was NOT a future work?

Comment: The show is on-going. That question falls under this question's penultimate group: "Are questions on series which are answered by upcoming episodes "time localised"?"

Comment: @Keen - The "upcoming episodes" part seems awfully unclear from just the question itself. if you feel it was crystal clear, may be open a Meta Q argumenting that and if there's consensus from community I'll vote to re-close.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment. In the long run they will almost certainly get an answer and, more's the point, who's to say that someone doesn't already have an answer from a leaked script, inside knowledge or just a really solid guess? - http://www.reddit.com/r/gallifrey/comments/2a3cis/discussion_leaked_doctor_who_scripts_for_series_8/

Comment: If knowing whether the answer is or isn't requiring future works requires you to be an expert on the franchise, then it's a case of either: (a) poorly worded question in need of editing or (b) NOT being an open-and-shut-case of needing to be closed.

Comment: My such closed questions have been deleted..

Comment: This edit changes the meaning of the answer

Comment: I agree with @Valorum the edit conflicts with the general usage of this question and breaks the policy.

Comment: @Edlothiad - I've rolled back to the previous version. This is an excellent perspective on the question but should be posted **as a separate answer** rather than being appended to an existing answer that says something different, not least because that answer has stood without amendment for more than three years and forms the basis for the existing policy.

Comment: @Valorum - it has always been an intended scope of the policy. I have never intended it to be used (and if it was so, it was incorrectly) to shut down general franchise questions ***merely because the franchise is not complete***. As proof of that, if you think things to their logical conclusion, any other application of this policy means that ***100% of new questions about Star Wars should be closed until entire franchise completes*** - even questions about Episode VII specifically are likely to have an answer "don't know yet; but may be answered in Episode IX" .

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To, there can be questions on a material that don't require the knowledge of future material to answer. However there also exist questions, that may be asked at the time a film in a series is produced, that (while asking about something from the film) are almost certain to be answered in a later film. While a we don't know answer works, it provides speculation, when a question could instead be put on hold until more information is provided. If that wasn't your original intention, you should write a new meta answer and see if people want to raise that one above this one.

Comment: @Edlothiad  - either there's an actual evidence (interview etc...) that the answer will be known in a future film - in which case, **that's a non-subjective correct answer, therefore not requiring VTC**. Or, there's no evidence that it will be definitively answered in a future work (but not current), in which case there's no basis for VTC as it doesn't fall under FW policy.

Comment: @Valorum How does the edit change the meaning of the answer? I read it as a clarification with examples of when to apply the policy and when not to, but no change to the actual policy.

Comment: @Valorum - I didn't change the policy. It was always intended to be that way if you actually think through it logically. Not my fault people (a) didn't bother and (b) didn't bother asking for clarifications (till now)

Comment: @Valorum - since I'm the one who wrote it, i know far better than you whether it changed the meaning. I never intended for it to be used to close legitimate questions, and wasn't aware people WERE misreading it and doing just that.

Comment: It's stood for three years without needing clarification. Your changes fundamentally alter the "workflow" you suggested.

Comment: @Valorum - no they do not. My edit (and comments) clearly explain why that's the case.

Comment: I still don't understand how the edit allegedly changes the policy, @Valorum and Edlothiad.

Comment: @Null - It fundamentally alters the answer; Version #1 - If a question is asked about a current work where the answer will (almost certainly) be part of a future work, it should be closed. Version #2 - Questions should only be closed as future works if they're questions that are directly about a work that hasn't been released yet.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - I disagree. This directly *alters* a long-established answer/

Comment: @Valorum I don't see how "version #1" ever existed. Both the title and body of the question this is answering refer to "questions about future works", i.e. "version #2". Also, stop editing the post.

Comment: @Null - *"Months/years later, correct canon answer is published"*.

Comment: @Valorum - you're contradicting yourself. You're fully in record - and in agreement with me - even in earlier comments - that we CAN'T KNOW FOR SURE whether the answer will or will not be part of a future work with any degree of certainty. Yet, you're asserting such certainty on a broad scope of questions. As noted in the edit, I fully agree that - if there's evidence that the question fully pertains to a future work - it is FW-compatible. Just not if it's a random guess.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - I was in broad agreement with the former workflow. If it turns out that there's actually an answer in some weird, obscure canon then post a comment and mark it to be reopened.

Comment: As Valorum says, this is exactly the current working of the policy, especially in the last 12 months

Comment: @Edlothiad And in the last couple of days, [many Star Wars questions closed under the alleged FWP](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11592/31936) have been re-opened despite the fact that Episode VIII didn't answer them.

Comment: @Null seems people need to be educated because for the past couple of years scores of posts have been closed for violating the FWP most prominently in the recent Game if Thrones craze. While they were then opened a week later it was when they were answerable

Comment: There appear to be two competing interpretations of this post. The appropriate place to discuss those interpretations are in another meta thread. Consequently, @DVK-on-Ahch-To I am rolling this back to the state of the post as it existed before today so that users can reference the original post in a new discussion. I personally don't think your clarifications have changed the policy, but apparently others do.

Comment: (from the rolled back edit) `"No answer known yet but may be revealed in future works" is an excellent answer but NOT a valid reason to VTC` I disagree with that concept as it will cause an extra step in the workflow where someone posts a "we don't know" answer, later either correcting the answer when new information comes out, or requiring a new answer with the new information. I don't see the need for that, since as @edl said, we can just pause the question until an answer comes out, _if at all_.

Comment: @Möoz - and how do you know that the answer won't be "oh this obscure comic last week answered it"?

Comment: Because enough people will have voted to close it. _That's the point of needing five votes to close_. Then, if enough people find that obscure comic somewhere, they can vote to re-open it (either some time after, or immediately).

Comment: @DVK one doesn't need to, that's the beauty of the re-open button. "The experts thought this wasn't answerable, here comes Billy bob with an answer" Billy bob flags for a mod to re-open, or edits to throw it in the queue, or uses one of their re-open votes. to get it in the queue and the community corrects their mistake. Rather than getting 10 "We don't know" answers and then the user going "oh actually we do know"

Comment: @Möoz - why don't we just close ALL questions then? then if enough people find an answer it can be re-opened.

Comment: @Edlothiad - we have an explicit policy that we don't close questions on the basis of "the answer isn't obvious and an expert didn't post one in 5 minutes". Your logic applies to 100% of the site questions, nothing to do with Future Works policy.

Comment: @DVK No it does not. There's a _huge_ difference between those that seem like they may be answered by a future work and those that don't. If you're unwilling to accept that then this discussion is moot.

Comment: @Edlothiad - I'm willing to accept that in some rare, exceptional, cases, the question is obviously only answerable from a future work. In the examples posted to Meta, 4 of 5 were NOT of taht type ; yet errorneously closed.

Comment: I think the site has proven time and again that it is far less rare than users seem to think. The examples posted here were a very niche select group, which hardly reflect the 10s of Thousands of questions we have on site. It is possible I've simply been exposed to more with my extremely high activity in the review queue, but it is significant.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that your edit makes this answer _not what we've been doing since you posted it_. It's cited so often, it even made it into FAQ. By editing your answer you're _effectively changing meta policy_ without the rest of us getting a chance to vote on it. We have always interpreted this answer to mean "if the question is not answerable now but might be answerable when more stuff comes out, close it and come back to it". We've been consistently applying this policy for _three years_ with no problems, but now you randomly decide you don't like it?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To we see _tons_ of questions, every time a new MCU or DCEU movie comes out, where the answer is "obviously, they're going to tell us in the sequel". _The Force Awakens_ generated these as well. (e.g. "How did Maz Kanata get Luke's lightsaber?"  Where do you get the impression that these are rare?

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that we don't always know if any future works are in the making, and if they are, if the question will be answered in them. If we take this to its extreme conclusion, we could only have questions about "dead and buried" canon, and we don't want that, do we?

Ignoring dead canons for now, we can discern different levels of liveliness in canons.
On the one hand, we have questions about movie trailers. We know that trailers are meant to pique people's interest, so they will often pose questions that are answered in the movie.
On the other hand, we have a canon like Harry Potter: mostly dead, but it's still added to in Pottermore — and then suddenly a whole new trilogy of movies get added.
Somewhere in between are TV series where a number of seasons have been broadcast, but new seasons are still in the making.

I think the close reason "opinion based" is the wrong reason to close these types of questions with. It is not a matter of opinion, it's a matter of speculation perhaps, but it's above all a matter of patience. **Questions such as these should be closed with a custom reason that boils down to "have patience", if the work in question is in production or already produced, but not published yet.** This should cover most movie trailer questions and questions about current seasons and story arcs of TV and other series.

With questions such as the *Avatar* question, where new information that wasn't necessarily expected, changes the correctness of a long-standing accepted answer, perhaps the best course of action is to re-ask and self-answer the question, then mark the original question as a duplicate.