# Why are these questions closed

Tags: support, closed-questions

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83085/where-is-marvel-cinematic-universe-heading

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83092/would-there-be-infinity-stone-in-avengers-age-of-ultron

These questions has been closed as primarily opinion based. How can these be opinion based when I am asking for official statements?

Comment: [Future works dude, future works!](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/21267). The general consensus is that we should close those Qs because there is **no way** to answer them with the current information we have. Any answer will be "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @Mooz Haven't you read my question? I am asking for official statements..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, these questions have no official answers. As such, we have four options:

- Ignore the question completely.
- Answer the question saying that there is no official answer.
- Answer the question saying that there is no official answer, provide (hopefully) reasonable logical speculation which may or may not be correct and need to be updated later.
- Close the question until such time that an official statement or answer *does* exist.

Per the discussion on [Should questions about future works be closed as Primarily Opinion Based?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based), the community consensus was that we should choose the fourth option and come back to it once someone finds an official answer.

If at any point, someone *can* find an official statement, a comment can be left and the question can be flagged for re-opening, or a mod can be contacted to get it re-opened quicker.

Especially since you are asking for official statements, the fourth option makes even more sense to help prevent the non-official answers you say you're not looking for.

Comment: As a mod, I'm happy to confirm that I'll immediately reopen any "opinion-based future" questions once there's a solid chance of answering them, for example after the release date.