# Re-open the question on Clara's death?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Shouldn't this question:

> [Do we know how Clara will leave series 9 of Doctor Who?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105080/do-we-know-how-clara-will-leave-series-9-of-doctor-who)

be re-opened? The closed reason is simply not true:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

The answer includes *"facts, references, or specific expertise."* It is well researched and interesting as well.

Please vote to re-open or post a corrective answer if I have misunderstood.

Comment: It's reopened :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since Clara's departure is a [future work](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5188/1027).

Admittedly, I'm behind on *Doctor Who*, but my understanding is she's leaving at the end of the season, which is not yet upon us.  If she's left in the past week or two, let me know, and I'll reopen that question.

Comment: Thank Keen. I have to confess you are right, but perhaps for a different reason? The question is not *whether* she will leave the series but *how*. The answer is indeed speculative in that respect.

Comment: With the acknowledgement that I'm not unbiased, I think it rather violates the *spirit* of the Future-Works policy, while technically squeaking past the *letter* (cc. @Wikis)

Comment: @JasonBaker: can you elaborate? I'm not sure if you are in favour or against re-opening this question?

Comment: @Wikis Although the question is asking about a future work, it's framed in such a way that it *is* objectively answerable; the question is technically "Do we know how..." not "How will...". The trivial answer is simply "no," and my answer is just "Here's Coleman saying 'no'". And I am trying to retain a semblance of neutrality, since I have a natural bias to having it re-opened =)

Comment: @JasonBaker: you can post a new answer if you like. Although I have accepted Keen's, I will change if your answer is persuasive.

Comment: @JasonBaker I don't find that persuasive, since in virtually no way will that be the answer.  The answer will be 'no, here's an interview where they address it', followed by another answer with a different interview, followed by another answer with a different interview.  All of which becomes worthless once the episode airs and someone posts an updated answer.

Comment: @Keen Fair enough, but we have answers go out of date because of changes to canon all the time. The difference here is that we have a definite point of time by which answers will be invalidated. Like I said, spirit versus letter