# Ep. VII: So many questions and none that can be answered... yet! Is this allowed?

Tags: discussion

Ok, I'll be honest, I already have a ton of questions regarding The Force Awakens and the 30 years aged Galaxy that is so Far Far Away.  However, some of these questions might be answered in this movie, they may be answered in supplemental texts (such as comics or novels) or, potentially, upcoming TV shows.

As such, I wanted to check and see if it is within the terms to ask *concrete* questions, which have specific answers that we can't reliably answer today.

My point is to stack the questions on this site so that as people find the information, that can fill in the details.

**EXAMPLE**

Just so you can get a feel for what I'm thinking, I would like to ask "Why is C-3PO's left arm red?"  This is a good question and from my snooping, we can't hope to find that out in the coming movie.  However, it has been mentioned that this minor detail will likely be addressed in a future comic book.

There is a specific answer to this, and I'm not interested in fan speculation.  However, since I'm probably not going to read a comic book nor pay attention to when it will be released, I would like to go ahead and ask the question so that some future-guru can fill in the blanks with reliable details.

Is this behavior allowed within the Q&A TOS?  My gut says that technically, yes, but this would be frowned upon with potential downvotes.

Comment: There is actually an [out-of-universe answer](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2015-11-10/jj-abrams-reveals-the-secret-of-c-3pos-red-arm-in-star-wars-the-force-awakens) to your question already. According to Jar Jar Abrams, his arm is red because having the character have spare parts is an excellent way to show the passage of time when dealing with a character who is essentially immortal.

Comment: Yes, I read that, and I understand JJ's decision.  However, what in-universe events led to this change?  That's what I'm primarily interested in, for this specific question.

Comment: Ah, well that won't be revealed until Feb 2016 with the release of the one-shot comic [Star Wars Special: C-3PO #1](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Special:_C-3PO_1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a community, we've had this discussion in the past, over questions that will likely be answered by some upcoming, as-yet-unpublished work. You can see the discussion and ultimate consensus here:

[Should questions about future works be closed as Primarily Opinion Based?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based)

The basic policy is: if the question is asking about something that hasn't been answered *yet* but might be answered in the *future*, it is likely to get closed (since any answers would be speculative and opinion-based.) At the point in the future where the answer is revealed, in theory we can simply ask for the question to be re-opened and answer it then. (In practice, this relies on the asker and answers to keep up with the status of the questions -- favorite them, etc. -- which is hard to guarantee.)

However, if the question is asking about out-of-universe information: press releases, trailers, interviews, ComicCon reveals, etc., that would typically not fall under the future works policy. Of course, the answer to those questions is often just "no, we don't know", making them much less interesting and likely to attract negative voting attention from the regulars.

Comment: Alternatively you could self-answer it with 'press release X teased it is going to be revealed in Force awakens comic #9'. That's a non-future works question that can be updated later.