# Future Works policy on The Rings of Power, a TV show that has not yet finished its first season

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, closed-questions, future-works

Currently, we have two questions asking about a comparison of the TV show, *The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power*, to its source material:

1. [How close is Amazon's 'The Rings of Power' to anything that existed in prior Tolkien works?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267475/7957)
2. [What has appeared in Rings of Power that is outside Lord of the Rings and The Hobbit, but still in Tolkien's writings?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267577/7957)

The first question is currently open (has been closed and was reopened) while the second question is currently closed for being about [future works](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5187). Currently, only three episodes out of the [five-season](https://www.empireonline.com/tv/news/lord-of-the-rings-power-five-seasons-fully-planned-out-exclusive/) TV show have been released so far, so I understand why the second question was closed for being about future works.

I don't get why the first question is open, though. It seems inconsistent with the treatment that the second question got. (When the first question was asked, only *two* episodes have been released.) They're both asking for a comparison of an in-progress TV show (which hasn't even reached *half* the episodes of its first season yet) to the source material.

Comment: The first question is essentially asking what is going to be covered in the show which can be answered from interviews, press releases, the show (eventually), license agreements, etc. The second is what has been in the show that is in other works which can only be answered once the show has aired.